# Comparing the sum of two pairs of non-identical random variables through bootstrapping

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-variable, bootstrap

I have 4 real-valued random variables, $A_i$ and $B_i$ $(i=1,2)$. I have $10000$ bootstrap samples for each. I can test if mean($A_1$)=mean($B_1$) or mean($A_2$)=mean($B_2$) [easily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Bootstrap_hypothesis_testing). But how do I test the hypothesis that mean($A_1+A_2$) = mean($B_1+B_2$) without assuming $A_1=A_2$ or $B_1=B_2$ or going back to the bootstrap generating process? Is it as simple as combining the bootstrap samples for the two $A_i$ into a single bootstrap $A$ (by addition), doing the same for $B_i$, and compare the two resultant "summed" bootstraps?

Comment: Might be, depending on the kind of bootstrap.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks. It's just the simplest kind of bootstrap: case resampling done with Monte Carlo.